# Vue CASL получить роль пользователя от Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, permissions, vuex, acl

Есть тестовый сайт на spring boot

В Vuex храним объект profile который хранит в себе roles

Есть модуль для разграничение доступа для пользователя на стороне vue - [CASL](https://stalniy.github.io/casl/)

Как все работает понятно, но для статических данных

ability.js

```
import {AbilityBuilder} from '@casl/ability'

var role = 'ADMIN'

export default
AbilityBuilder.define(can => {
    switch (role) {
        case 'USER':
            can('read', 'Help Desk Task');
            break;
        case 'ADMIN':
            can('update', 'Help Desk Task');
            break;
    }
})
```

Как в переменную role получить данные из vuex state?

Если я делаю следующим путем то на момент обработки этого кода profile еще не инициализирован и я ничего не получу, если получать через геттер тоже самое

```
import store from 'store/store'
var role = store.state.profile.roles
```

Вот main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import '@babel/polyfill'
import store from 'store/store'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import App from 'pages/App.vue'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
import router from 'router/router'
import { abilitiesPlugin } from '@casl/vue'
import ability from 'ability/ability'

Vue.use(abilitiesPlugin, ability)
Vue.use(Vuetify)
Vue.use(VueResource)
Vue.use(require('vue-moment'))

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    store,
    render: a => a(App),
})
```

Или как в main.js получить роль пользователя из Vuex

Answer (score 4):

Была такая же проблема. Можно поступить следующим образом:

ability.js

```
import { AbilityBuilder, Ability } from '@casl/ability'

// инициализируем ability, но роли еще не известны
export const ability =
   AbilityBuilder.define(can => {
      // can('load', 'all');
});

// функция для создания правил, воспользуемся когда нам потребуется
export function defineAbilityFor(role) {
  const { rules, can, cannot } = AbilityBuilder.extract();

  switch (role) {
    case 'USER':
        can('read', 'Help Desk Task');
        break;
    case 'ADMIN':
        can('update', 'Help Desk Task');
        break;
   }

   return new Ability(rules);
}
```

Например, имеется компонент Login.vue или любой другой, зависит от вашего приложения, это только в качестве примера:

```
import store from 'store/store'
import { defineAbilityFor } from '../abilities'

const role = store.state.profile.roles

    ...
methods: {
    defineRole() {
      // в свойствах компонента доступен объект $ability
      // обновляем правила когда нам это необходимо
      this.$ability.update(
           defineAbilityFor(role).rules
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: здорово 
но ведь придется делать так в каждом компоненте, а это неправильно.
нужно найти как расшарить для всех
но все равно спасибо за ответ)

Comment: Я делал так как вам описал, только в одном компоненте: пользователь регистрируется и сервер отдает роль клиенту - создаем правила. Все, больше никаких манипуляций, не нужно в каждом компоненте это делать, правила созданы для всего приложения.

Comment: Ооу, да, получилось.
Спасибо большое, я бы до такого не додумался